# How can i get content between dates using java regular expressions

Tags: java, regex

Below code did not get me the content between dates.can you please help me.

```
String res="05/22/2014 03:22:39.288 ffff gggg kkkkkk lllllll ssss 05/22/2014 03:22:39.288 oooooo ppppp qqqq rrrrrr sss 05/22/2014 03:22:39.378 mmmmmm nnn oooo ";   

String regEx="((0?[1-9]|1[012])/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/((19|20)\\d\\d).*([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9].[\\d]*)(.*?)((0?[1-9]|1[012])/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/((19|20)\\d\\d).*([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9].[\\d]*)?";

Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regEx).matcher(res);

while(matcher.find())
{
  String group = matcher.group();
  System.out.println(group);
}
```

Even i tried below using string split with regular expression in java  but it gives only one result:

```
String regEx="((0?[1-9]|1[012])/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/((19|20)\\d\\d).*([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9].([\\d][^\\s]+)?)";
        String[] split = res.split(regEx);
```

Comment: Where is input text coming from? Do you have to validate dates also?

Comment: only 05/22/2014 03:22:39.288 type of datetime i need to accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex to capture your text:

```
(?<=\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3} )(.*?)(?=(?: \d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}|$))
```

And grab your text in group #1 i.e.

```
matcher.group(1);
```

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/kX3dU3)

Comment: thank you.i did not got last one i.e front it has date but not last

Comment: its not working if in content in multiple lines like below 2 comments

Comment: 05/22/2014 03:22:39.288 oooooo ppppp qqqq rrrrrr sss

Comment: 08/23/2014 \n03:22:39.345 mmmmmm nnn oooo

Comment: For `05/22/2014 03:22:39.288 oooooo ppppp qqqq rrrrrr sss` it gives: `oooooo ppppp qqqq rrrrrr sss`

Comment: see it working here: http://regex101.com/r/iK9dQ5 In Java make sure your `Pattern.DOTALL` parameter in your regex.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you only get one result in the split is that the * operator is greedy in a regex. Take a read of this, it's good stuff: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html